# Deploy Web Apps with different dotnet targets using Azure Resource Manager Template

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I'm trying to deploy a collection of web services using the Azure Resource Manager Template from Visual Studio 2017. 
When following the tutorial [Deploy code with your infrastructure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy#deploy-code-with-your-infrastructure)from Microsoft, to deploy an asp.net core 1.1 web app, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Common.targets(87,5): 
error : Project 'C:\.........\MobileAPI.csproj' targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'.  
It cannot be referenced by a project that targets 'Deployment,Version=1.0'.
Done building project "MobileAPI.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

I already changed the target in the "MobileAPI.csproj" to '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1' then it builds the project but does not recognize the "Package" in "Include Targets".

Has anybody an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: When adding reference to the .NET Core project, the Additional Properties, Include File Path and Include Targets properties will not be set automatically for the referenced project. Have you set these properties properly?

Comment: I'm aware of that. I have set the "Additional Properties", the "Include File Path" and the "Include targets" according to the Tutorial.

Comment: As a workaround, you could upload your project to GitHub and deploy the app linked to a GitHub repository.  [Deploy a web app linked to a GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-github-deploy)